# Parsing XML returned from Webserver vb.net

Tags: .net, xml, winforms, parsing

I get this XML data from my web application

```
<api_result>
    <send_info>
    <eventid>0</eventid>
    </send_info>
    <call_result>
        <result>False</result>
        <error>No data to send</error>
    </call_result>
</api_result>
```

how do i get the `<result>` content and the  content, i.e false and error?

This is what i did:

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
    `xmldoc.LoadXml(sTempUrl)`    <-- this line gives error
    Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("error") 
    sError = xmlnode(0).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
```

however I am getting this error in the bold line:

`Cannot load XmlDataDocument if it already contains data. Please use a new XmlDataDocument.`

Comment: In which line do you get an error?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt i have added the error line

Comment: It seems that your XmlDataDocument is not empty when you call LoadXml, are you sure you do nothing in the middle of creating object and loading from string?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt yes i did use it for some operation before, how do i empty it?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt i don't undestand, please show me d line you changed

Comment: Load function doesn't work when XmlDataDocument is not empty, so your need to load xml in empty document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use empty XmlDataDocument when loading from file or string, so I guess you problem is here.
As I remember .Net 2 supports Select method, which is more elegant way to get element from xml. see [XmlDataDocument.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.selectnodes.aspx), but this is not your case, just create new XmlDataDocument on loading.

Hope this helps